# Contagem de coordenadas no MATLAB

Tags: matriz

Olá.
Tenho uma matriz 8x2:

M = [1 2; 5 8; 3 1; 6 6; 7 1; 1 2; 3 1; 7 1];

Gostaria de contar quantas vezes cada linha (x,y) se repete.

O resultado deverá ficar, por exemplo, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tentativa:**

```
[i,j]=hist(M,unique(M)); out=[j' sum((i),2)]
```

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: Tentei isso: [i,j]=hist(M,unique(M)); out=[j' sum((i),2)]. Mas eles está somando cada elemento e não o par x,y.